# Database query to search using address

Tags: sql, oracle

I am developing a search functionality to search for dealers by their address(i.e. by postcode(zip) or by name or by city)for my project. user will be provided with only one html input field to enter the search term (users can enter only one search term at a time, i.e. either zip code or name or city (combinations are not allowed)). The conditions to develop a query are as below

1. When user search by zip code, matched results should be displayed in descending order
2. When user search by name matched results should be display alphabetically
3. Same as city name

Some times there is a possibility that name can also contains zip code in that case results should be shorted by zip code.

I tried like this

```
select city, postcode, name
  from dealers
  where name ='xyz' OR
        postcode ='xyz' OR
        city='XYZ'
  ORDER BY postcode desc
```

But I want 'ORDER BY' for every condition. for example 'xyz' matches to the first name I want to sort the result in ascending order. How can I do that?

Comment: seems like you need someone to do it for you

Comment: along with the text field add radio buttons or a combo box for selecting what they have input, whether it is name, zip code etc.  so depending on that you can sort

Comment: Post your tables structure and some data to test. Also some query to start from. Is this a homework?

Comment: @user964147 sql is not that difficult to learn. try it yourself, you will discover many things that can be done in many ways

Comment: for names and city consider using LIKE atleast for names

Comment: try, this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24022/Simple-way-to-implement-database-driven-Advance-Se

Comment: @FirmView thank you very much for your prompt reply. i already tried with union.mysql throwing exception when i used ORDER BY in both select statements

Comment: How does your code determine if the input is a postcode, name, or city? Further, if you're searching by postcode, why ORDER by postcode? Doesn't seem to make sense. Ditto for name and city.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Life would be easier if all your terms were sorted in ascending order.

I assume that your actual application is using a variable rather than a hard-coded string.  So the solution should look something like this:

```
  select city, postcode, name
  from dealers
  where name = p_search_term OR
        postcode = p_search_term OR
        city = p_search_term
  ORDER BY case when postcode = p_search_term then p_search_term else 1 end desc
           , case when name = p_search_term then p_search_term else city end asc
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, your answer really saved my day

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you do it like this:

```
     "SELECT `zip`, `name`, `city` FROM `dealers` WHERE `zip` = '$zip' ORDER BY `zip` DESC"
     "SELECT `zip`, `name`, `city` FROM `dealers` WHERE `name` = '$name' ORDER BY `name`"
     "SELECT `zip`, `name`, `city` FROM `dealers` WHERE `city` = '$city' ORDER BY `city`"
```

I don't use Oracle but I think that it is the same. (This code assumes that zip is a varchar, if it is an integer value just remove the ' ')

Comment: Oracle has the same notation except that you do not use the (`) character before and after column names

Comment: i think for names, LIKE can be considered

Comment: @Manolis Thanks a lot for your reply. I have only one input box, i am finding difficulty in how to combine all these and get correct result

Comment: I think you sould add also 3 radio buttons to make the user select the type of his input. Ok, you can detect if it is a valid zip, but how you know if the input is a name or a city, they can both contain [A-Z][a-z] characters.