# how to write a database query to search for the customers using address

Tags: sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Database query to search using address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538926/database-query-to-search-using-address)

I am developing a search functionality to search for dealers by their address (i.e by postcode(zip) or by name or by city) for my project. User will be provided with only one html input field to enter the search term (users can enter only one search term at a time i.e either zip code or name or city (combinations are not allowed)).

The conditions to develop a query are as below

- when user search by zip code, matched results should be displayed in descending order
- when user search by name matched results should be display alphabetically same as city name

Some times there is a possibility that name can also contains zip code in that case results should be shorted by zip code.

I tried like this

```
select city, postcode, name 
from dealers 
where name ='xyz' 
 OR postcode ='xyz' 
 OR city='XYZ' 
ORDER BY postcode desc
```

But Ii want `ORDER BY` for every condition. for example 'xyz' matches to the firstname I want to sort the result in ascending order.

How can i do that? Any suggestions will be greatly appriciated

Comment: More than a possible duplicate. Same question by same user. @user964147, please move any information that this question has, that the previous question didn't, to the previous question, using edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  city, postcode, name 
FROM 
  dealers
WHERE 
...
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN @postcodeParam IS NOT NULL THEN postcode END DESC,
  CASE WHEN @nameParam     IS NOT NULL THEN name     END, 
  CASE WHEN @citynameParam IS NOT NULL THEN cityname END
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, your suggestion made me to think out of the box on my task.

Comment: This is not Oracle syntax, which is a small point.  The bigger point is that the application has "only one html input field", so only one parameter will be passed to the query.

Comment: @APC, Sorry for that. I tried to delete it, but it tells me that I can't delete an accepted answer. I am not familiar with the oracle syntax but I know it has the `CASE` expression so I wrote it this way and for the three parameters, I noticed he comparing the name, postcode and cityname to parameters so I thought there are three different parameters passed to the query so I wrote it this way.But I think the `ORDER BY` clause is what he was looking for, and I didn't realize that it is a duplicate, so I posted it. But feel free to edit the answer or flag to delete it.